# Search (Ctrl + F) multiple word at the same time in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am working on an Excel file and I have a list of word that I need to search and if I find it I have to highlight its column.

I want to use CTRL+F but I can only copy and paste one word at the time so I was wandering if there is a way to automate this task by using VBA or Conditional formatting.

I have looked on the web but the solutions are not feting well to my problem.

Comment: How many words are you looking to search for? if it's only a handful, setting up conditional formatting would be easy enough. If it's more, you'll probably need VBA

Answer (score 1):

I found this on mrexcel.com ([Find records and put into a summary sheet](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/145696-find-records-put-into-summary-sheet-solved.html)) and modified it quickly (thanks to BrianB).

Watch your tabs are named like they are named in the code. This is just to help quick and show you one way, it's not very good edited or further commented by me.

```
Sub FindRecords()
    Dim FromSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FromRow As Long
    Dim ToSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ToRow As Long
    Dim FindThis As Variant
    Dim FoundCell As Object
    '---------------------------------------------------
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set FromSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")
    Set ToSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    ToRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
    '---------------------------------------------------
    '- get user input
    FindThis = InputBox("Please enter data to find : ")
    If FindThis = "" Then End ' trap Cancel
    '---------------------------------------------------
    '- clear summary for new data
    'ToSheet.Cells.ClearContents
    '---------------------------------------------------
    ' FIND DATA
    '-
    With FromSheet.Cells
        Set FoundCell = .Find(FindThis, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
            '------------------------------------------
            '- copy data to summary
            'Do
                FromRow = FoundCell.Row
                ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 1).Value = _
                        FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, 1).Value
                ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 2).Value = _
                        FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, 2).Value
                ToSheet.Cells(ToRow, 3).Value = _
                        FromSheet.Cells(FromRow, 3).Value
                ToRow = ToRow + 1
                'Set FoundCell = .FindNext(FoundCell)
            'Loop While Not FoundCell Is Nothing And _
             '   FoundCell.Address <> FirstAddress
            '------------------------------------------
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox ("Done.")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    FindRecords
End Sub
```